# Adaptive Positioning Based on iOS Device

Tags: ios, dynamic, cocos2d-iphone, positioning

I made an iPhone game a few months ago, and am now trying to port it as a universal app to both the iPad and iPhone 5 with Cocos2D. I was wondering if there was a simple-ish way to determine where an object should be placed based on the device running the game.

I could use if statements to figure out which device the game is running on, so when I get the correct sized images for the device I could have separate positions for each object, but it seems like there would be a maths formula which would allow me to use a lot less code. Obviously something like a full screen background is very simple, because it just needs to be centred with:

```
[background setPosition:CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2)];
```

I haven't a clue how to adapt a button that would be X = 144 & Y = 330 on the old 3.5inch, 640 by 960 resolution iPhone to an iPad or iPhone 5 resolution.

I'm willing to use a more recent version of iOS if it will make my life easier, but because I'm not using any of Apple's objects I don't know if that is possible.

Maybe this isn't even possible because the button will be different sizes for the iPhone and iPad version, but I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, i am usually facing the same problem,
but if it is just a static objects placement 
i would have `relative coordinates instead of absolute` for every object
and then use screen sizes to place them correctly 
so you might want to use a function like:

```
-(CGPoint) relativeToScreen:(CGPoint) p { 
    return ccp(screenSize.width * p.x, screenSize.height * p.y) 
}
```

where 0.0 <= p.x =< 1.0 and the same for p.y

and don't forget about your `anchorPoint`, because the node position is based on it as well

and i hope you have discovered that cocos2d already does image choosing instead of you,
you just have to set right suffixes for your images: `-hd, -ipad, -ipadhd`

Answer (score 0):

For iphone5 resolution, I position hud buttons relative to the screen dimensions. Very similar to what you are doing for the background. So for example, a pause button I want in the top left I would position like this:

```
[pauseButton setPosition:CGPointMake(0.0f + 30.0f, screenSize.height - 50.0f)];
```

For ipad it gets really tricky. The lazy way which I have implemented is to play around with the content scale factor and zoom everything up and have "dead" borders to compensate for the ipad's screen ratio. Not the best, but at least you can re-use all the same assets for the ipad.